# unable to send push notification to mobile-Failed connect to notification:80

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Hi all need your guys help, I building new mobile application and I have problem to send notification to my mobile app using parse using javascript. I upload below code in cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
Parse.Push.send({channels: [ "AppJSTest" ],data: {
 alert: "Quit Your Jibba Jabba"}}, { success: function() { alert: "success function"},error: function(err) { alert: "fail function"}});  response.success("Hello world!");});
```

Below my file in mobile application main.js:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
Parse.initialize(PARSE_APP, PARSE_JS);

NoteObject = Parse.Object.extend("NoteObject");

function getNotes() {
    var query = new Parse.Query(NoteObject);

    query.find({
        success:function(results) {
            console.dir(results);
            var s = "";
            for(var i=0, len=results.length; i<len; i++) {
                var note = results[i];
                s += "<p>";
                s += "<b>"+note.get("title")+"</b><br/>";
                s += "<b>Written "+note.createdAt + "<br/>";
                s += note.get("body");
                s += "</p>";
            }
            $("#notes").html(s);
        },
        error:function(error) {
            alert("Error when getting notes!");
        }
    });
}

$("#addNoteBtn").on("touchend", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Grab the note details, no real validation for now
    var title = $("#noteTitle").val();
    var body = $("#noteBody").val();

    var note = new NoteObject();
    note.save({title:title, body:body}, {
        success:function(object) {
            console.log("Saved the object!");
            $("#noteTitle").val("");
            $("#noteBody").val("");
            getNotes();
        }, 
        error:function(object,error) {
            console.dir(error);
            alert("Sorry, I couldn't save it.");
        }
    });
});

//call getNotes immediately
getNotes();});
```

and I trigger to parse manually with below script from parse command line:

```
curl -X POST \ -H "X-Parse-Application-Id:kNZ1hmD7KFUdf7zcKQG8t19ZPC04itHpcnIrqAqz" \ -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key:EDrUjXegE1ec01MmlWYo4IqjrG1sphFd3Vkk8OKR" \ -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ -d '{}' \ https://api.parse.com/1/push/hello
```

what wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous JavaScript will get you every time.   Move `response.success(...)` into the success callback you're providing to Parse.Push, so that it actually waits for the push to be submitted before quitting.